# System.PlatformNotSupportedException from CompileAssemblyFromSource

Tags: c#, exception

So working on a little project, I needed to compile some text files into executables for optimization sake and so on. When I ran the code that was supposed to compile the file, it stopped and gave me that exception on CompileAssemblyFromSource. And after looking into some potential fixes, I realized I have no idea on what is causing this problem and how I would be able to fix it. Given the origin of the exception, apperantly something I use has a version in which CompileAssemblyFromSource is not compatible with but then the problem arises, I don't know what doesn't have a compatible version and I'm not sure how to actually apply a fix to it.

Note: I'm sure its not something with my .NET Network version, neither .NET or .NET Core since I checked their versions already and it seemed to be one that is compatible with CAFS. So I'm stumped.

This is the code I'm using to create an executable if its helps.

```cs
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, path, true);
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

var code = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user\source\repos\M-KDTEA_main\M-KDTEA_main\keys\en-us\en-us_ekey.txt");
var results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue porting an old application to dotnet core.
That's because the CodeDom compiler, available on dotnet "classic", is not available for dotnet core.
But you can use the roselyn compiler to do similar work instead.
I was able to make my application work following [this article](https://www.tallan.com/blog/2019/09/12/compiling-and-running-a-dll-in-net-core-2-using-roslyn-and-reflection/) (replacing VisualBasic by CSharp) which leverages the [roselyn analyzer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxtree?view=roslyn-dotnet) to build code on the fly and load assemblies.

Comment: no worries, don't forget to mark my answer as answer :)